# How to use different color for effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Working Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9u0ggeLL/3/

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li id="one"><a>Dashboard</a></li>
    <li id="two"><a>My Account</a></li>
    <li id="three"><a>Direct Messages</a></li>
</ul>
```

How can I modify the script, so depending on the child item that is hovered, it will animate with the color `ink` class based on the index.

I also, would like to set the background color to that after the animation stops.

I tried the following and it just keeps adding new span: https://jsfiddle.net/9u0ggeLL/4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly you can add an array of the colours you want to use to your code:

```
var colors = ['red','blue','green'];
```

Then inside the `hover` handler you can assign the colour from the array using the `index` variable you already have access to:

```
ink.css('background-color', colors[index]);
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/9u0ggeLL/5/)

Alternatively, it would be more both more extensible and easier to maintain if you assign the colours to the parent elements in CSS and then read them in the JS code, like this:

```
#one { color: #C00; }
#two { color: #0C0; }
#three { color: #00C; }
```

```js
ink.css('background-color', parent.css('color'));
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/9u0ggeLL/8/)

Comment: Awesome... :) Thanks. I had it working another way just a modification to what I did...https://jsfiddle.net/9u0ggeLL/7/.

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Comment: Do you recommend setting the background color to that after the animation? I would like to change the bg to the color that it is animating.

Comment: No you would need to do it before the animation, otherwise it will be the default orange colour, as per the CSS